# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError While inserting data

Tags: node.js, json, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm following a MERN toturial on building a ecommerce website. I'm having **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError** this error occurs when I try to insert data into database using postman and I,m not able to warp my head arount it.

**Here's the Error**

> (node:4864) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Product validation failed: category: Please enter product category, price: Please enter product price, description: Please enter product description, name: Please enter product name
> at model.Document.invalidate (D:\Project\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2907:32)
> at D:\Project\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2698:17
> at D:\Project\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1280:9
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

**This is the database connection file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const connectDatabase = () =>{
    
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI).then((data)=>{
            console.log(`Mongodb connected with server ${data.connection.host}`);
        }).catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        })

}
module.exports = connectDatabase;
```

**This is the schema**

```
const mongoose =  require("mongoose");

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter product name"],
        trim:true,
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter product description"],
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true, "Please enter product price"],
        maxLength:[7,"Price cannot exceed 7 characters"],
    },
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },
    images:[
        {
            public_id:{
                type:String,
                required:true,
            },
            url:{
            
                type:String,
                required:true,
            }
        }
    ],
    category:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "Please enter product category"],
    },
    stock:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true, "Please enter product Stock"],
        maxlength:[4, "Stock cannot exceed 4 characters"],
        default:1,
    },
    numberOfReviews:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,
    },
    
reviews:[
    {
        name:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        },
        rating:{
            type:Number,
            required:true,
        },
        comment:{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        }
    }
],
    createdAt:{
        type:Date,
        default:Date.now,
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

This is the json file that I send through POST and the postman kept stuck on sending request.

```
    "name":"product1",
    "price":12000,
    "description":"this is a sample product",
    "category":"Laptop",
    "images":{
        "public_id":"sample Image",
        "url":"sampleurl"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not in JSON format.In postman send data like this:

```
{
    "name":"product1",
    "price":12000,
    "description":"this is a sample product",
    "category":"Laptop",
    "images":{
        "public_id":"sample Image",
        "url":"sampleurl"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data as JSON not as text type in postman.

[image: send data as JSON not as text type in postman]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).